# How can I resolve this problem in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have a Movie component that holds the info of a given movie, I want users to comment about this movie but I want to give them the tools to mark as spoiler some parts of their comments.
I am using a Markdown editor and parser so users can style their comment and I created a 'new' tag for spoilers, example:

> "I watched that movie yesterday and was awesome. *s* The killer was
>   Tim!! That was a good plot *s* bla bla bla

So this is my problem, I can wrap what is inside "*s*" and convert it into html tags and create a button along that show the spoiler.

```
<div class="spoiler" style='display:hidden'>The killer was Tim!! That was a good plot</div>
<button>Show Spoiler</button> bla bla bla
```

And using [innerHtml] I can make it work with angular custom click bind to the button and stuff

But is this the best way to archieved that? In my mind what I would I do  (and doesn't work) is replace *s* tags with a component tag like 
`"<app-spoiler>...</app-spoiler>"` but with AOT compiler I would have to create a dinamic component and a dinamic module to archieve this and I don't think that would be good in terms of performance, if the movie has 20 comments, that would be a mess in my opinion.

Another solution I have ocurred is find all the spoilers tags and store an array of parts of the comment like

```
[{type: 'text', content:'Bla bla bla bla bla bla', {type:'spoiler', content: 'The spoiler text'}]
```

So in my template I would iterate through this array and if the type is spoiler, then show the `<app-spoiler></app-spoiler>` component:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of arrayOfTexts">
<ng-container *ngIf="text.type === 'text'">{{text}}</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="text.type === 'spoiler'"><app-spoiler>{{text}}</app-spoiler></ng-container>
```

Do you think that would really be a good solution? If I would have to implement more "tags" I think it would be "easy" to extend with this solution but I am looking for advices.

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think there should be any problem using `<app-spoiler>...</app-spoiler>`

Comment: I don't know how then, innerHtml don't work with components (they dissapear) and if I use normal brackets like {{comment}} with html tags, angular sanitizes.This is what I mean https://codesandbox.io/s/xkll6kz7z

Answer (score 0):

Here is an online [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnxl6a) you can check, is this what you need?

Here the code you trying to implement with some tweaks.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of arrayOfTexts">
<ng-container *ngIf="text.type === 'text'">{{text.content}} </ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="text.type === 'spoiler'">
    <app-spoiler [text]="text.content"></app-spoiler>
</ng-container>
```

Here I use SpoilerComponent with two variables, I think this will help you.

```
export class SpoilerComponent  {
  @Input() text: string;
  isShown: boolean;
}
```

I use `isShown` to hide the Spoiler text for initial and on click, it will be shown the spoiler text.

> Please comment if you need anything else or my understanding is different.

Comment: That's it, exactly. And I know how to implement it but I don't know if is the best solution given the problem but in terms of performance I think would be good. Thank you

Comment: glad it helps you. I used this type in productions, but if anyone has a better solution it's always welcome. :D.

Comment: @Kolter If this is completed your query, could you please accept the answer.